# Django jobs board post

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm new to Django and am learning by creating a website, as I find the django docs and most tutorials to be fair too technical for me to read.

I'm trying to create a webpage within my site that would post jobs as they become available, for a user base of employees to search through and accept jobs as they wish. The problem is I'm struggling to conceptualise it in Django.

For example, could I write a class-based view:

```
class JobPost(generic.CreateView):
    # more job specific relevant stuff goes here
    #...
    template_name = 'jobpost.html'
```

jobpost.html would then be a small section of code that gets included onto a larger webpage (jobsboard.html).

Is this the right track to be moving down?

I've looked everywhere for an answer/clues to how to do this. I find Django has very little in the way of beginner-friendly, jargon-free help and tutorials, and it's hard even to formulate the google search that would yield results. 
 Even just a link to put me on the right track would be a fantastic answer to my question.

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: https://djangobook.com/the-django-book/, have you gone through?

Comment: I did read through most of that, maybe I'll read through a second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this tutorial](https://djangoforbeginners.com/message-board/) which is similar enough to give a lot of useful direction.

Also [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/dynamic_data_in_templates/).